# TortoiseSVN: How to clear "diff with" list?

Tags: tortoisesvn

Somehow I managed to add a "Diff with LOCALFILENAME" entry to the TortoiseSVN context menu:

[image: Additional Diff with entry]

My question is: How can you clear that list/delete that entry? I don't want to have this entry anymore showing all the time for every file I right click.

Answer (score 0):

Diff the file once and the command in the context menu will disappear.

Comment: Thanks, but that did not help unfortunately.